# How do I test a custom TCP implementation on Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

For learning purposes I'm implementing TCP (for now just RFC 793) but I have no
idea how to test it. Most TUN/TAP stuff on the internet are out of date (e.g.
Linux API calls no longer work) and just doesn't explain enough. In addition, I
feel like a creating a device and forwarding packages etc. are not the best way
for learning purposes. For example, I'd rather only override `socket()`,
`listen()`, `connect()`, `accept()`, `send()`, `recv()` etc. in a program rather
than forwarding *all* ethernet traffic to a device/program that does the
bookeeping for the whole system rather than for a single program.

I'm wondering if this is possible. If not, I'd like to know the simplest way to
test a TCP implementation on Linux.

Because I'm following RFC 793, it'd be great if I could have an IP (Internet
Protocol as mentioned in the RFC) API in my application. Is this possible or do
I have to mess with TUN/TAP stuff?

Thanks..

Comment: I am trying to better understand your question. Do you have a TCP stack which you have implemented and you want to be able to test that? There are at-least two ways you can, you want to test your TCP stack as a server and then connect any 'standard' client (like telnet to it.). Some heavy lifting you have to do is - to be able to implement listen and accept like functionality yourself on the TCP stack - but that would be a starting point - Assume - you get input IP datagrams. The other way is to test it as a client, first.

Answer (score 2):

If we talk about research I strongly recommend you read [Engineering with Logic: Rigorous Test-Oracle Specification and
Validation for TCP/IP and the Sockets API](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/Netsem/paper3.pdf)

It contains section about testing TCP/IP implementation:
*"EXPERIMENTAL VALIDATION: TESTING INFRASTRUCTURE"*

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting up two peers, one using a RAW socket and the other a TCP socket.

If they can communicate and packets are really delivered/recovered the same way TCP does, you know that your custom implementation is successful.

[C sockets](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~moorthy/Courses/os98/Pgms/socket.html)

[C RAW sockets](http://www.tenouk.com/Module43a.html)

[C TCP implementation](https://github.com/TC1211/TCP)

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to intercept all tcp packets with bits (syn, ack, fin, etc.) your application has sent and to see if it works properly:

[image]

It could simply be done with wireshark or other sniffer. When testing you will see all tcp packets with bits you've sent.

[image]

In order you want to see linux system calls which your application are calling, you can use GDB or any other debugger.